# Render japanese font in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cjk, shinyapps

[image: ggplot]

I am creating a R shiny web app, which I have to publish in Japanese. The application plots many graphs, mainly using ggplot2.

After I run my application on my local machine, the browser renders all Japanese fonts in & outside ggplot correctly. However, when I upload it in shiny-apps, ggplot does not render Japanese text in Japanese characters.

I have already tried few tricks on stack overflow without any luck.

I am using a Windows machine, and have changed my local RStudio settings to utf8.
Shinyapps is by default utf8

Comment: thanks Z.Lin for editing